# Does 'blanc' have a special meaning, or does the author of org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfigurationLayout have a typing impediment?

Tags: java, apache-commons, properties-file

Apache commons configuration has a class called `PropertiesConfigurationLayout` that has methods like `getBlancLinesBefore()`.  I assume this is intentional, since it is very consistent.  The comment says "Returns the number of blanc lines before this property key."

To my knowledge, 'blanc' is not an English word (and simply means 'white' in French).  Is there some specialised techie meaning of 'blanc' that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I highly doubt this but... the author possibly meant "blank".

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect it's just a spelling mistake for "blank". Nothing special, just a spelling mistake. Quite possibly the original author was not a native English speaker.

I'd expect a "blank" line to either be defined as an *empty* line, or one which just consists of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the author speaks french, so that blanc indicates white?